Propulsion without reaction mass. Linear version of Feynman disc paradox
I am interested in exploring a linear (instead of rotational) version of Feynman´s disc paradox.
Super-conducting loop
To re-iterate this Feynman disc paradox we are looking at a situation where we have a super-conducting loop carrying a current, combined with carriers of electrical charge fixed at the circumference of this loop.

Initially this super-conducting loop plus charge carriers are assumed to be non-rotating.
When the temperature of the system is raised enough to cause an electrical resistance in the loop, then the magnetic field will be quenched and the disc will start spinning.

This effect can be explained by the non-zero angular momentum carried by the combination of the electrical and the magnetic field prior to quenching the magnetic field, hence the total angular momentum of the system remains conserved, even though the disc appears to start spinning without any externally applied torque or reaction-mass ejected.
Long rectangular loop made of a super-conducting wire
Now let us try to modify this setup to create a system that is able to accelerate and decelerate linearly in empty space without expelling any reaction mass or spending energy. Therefore let us consider a long rectangular loop made of a super-conducting wire.

Initially we assume the current through this loop to be zero.
If a nonzero current is applied then the system essentially consists of 2 long parallel super-conducting wires with currents of equal magnitude but in opposite directions, connected at the endpoints so that the current can flow unimpeded.
Now lets add a positive electric charge parallel to one of the long wires and an equal amount of negative electric charge parallel to the other long wire. The system is still at rest in our reference frame.

Current though the super-conducting loop
Now lets gradually build up a current though the super-conducting loop. This will create a magnetic field in addition to the electric fields which are due to the static charges aligned with the 2 parallel wires.

The Poynting vectors of the E and B fields in the vicinity of both wires will point the same way and in the direction of the wires.
The electromagnetic field in the space surrounding both wires will now carry a net nonzero momentum, and conservation of the total momentum dictates that the system accelerates in the direction opposite to the increasing momentum vector of the electromagnetic field.
As soon as the electric current is stabilized the system will maintain a constant nonzero speed relative to our reference frame.

To stop this movement all one needs to do is to reduce the current in the loop to zero. No net energy was spent and no reaction mass was expelled to accelerate and subsequently decelerate.
Any thoughts on the feasibility of such a system in connection with space-travel?

..no energy is spent, clearly if here is a nonzero poynting vector that will tell you the direction of EM radiation out of the system so clearly energy so being removed from the system.

Paragraphs are a wonderful tool to help write clearly.

This sort of propulsion system is known as a photon rocket. The momentum gained by the system during that initial transient state comes by ejecting EM waves anisotroically.
The design you suggest is not particularly strongly isotropic, so you will send a decent amount of energy wastefully in all directions. These drives are much more efficient if you can strongly collimate and focus the EM waves.

No net energy was spent and no reaction mass was expelled to accelerate and subsequently decelerate.

This is not correct. These systems are very inefficient. Almost all of the energy ends up in the EM wave. Very little winds up in the KE of the photon rocket.

Please note that there are no real photons emitted in this experiment (nor in Feymans disc thought experiment) as the increase or decrease of the current though the loop can be done in an adiabatically slow manner, thereby avoiding emission of EM waves. The static E and B field can be described in terms of virtual photons, but they are not emitted towards infinity as free photons would travel, and the energy they carry is equal to the energy of the static EM field.

Go ahead and work out the math for that. Doing it slowly is just going to radiate weakly for longer.

Have you looked into the Feynman disc paradox? This paradox is not explained by emitted radiation. To be able to effectively serve as a RF antenna there is a characteristic timescale of the order of the dimension of the system divided by the speed of light. Switching an electromagnet much slower than this timescale ensures that no significant portion of the energy is radiated away. This is why transmission lines do not radiate away a large portion of the energy they carry as this current oscillates with a period of only 1/60Hz which is slow compared to the ratio of length/c.

@Donkey yes, I am well aware of Feynman’s disk. This isn’t that

An equivalent, although less optimized, realization of this experiment would be to take the Feynman disc, this time with only 2 static charges at opposite sides of the center, then reverse the sign of 1 of the 2 static charges. If you accept that the Feynman disc with equal charges starts spinning when the magnetic field decays, then it will also be clear that with opposite charges the disc will start moving (without spinning as the torques exerted by the 2 opposite charges now cancel, while the forces exerted by the charges now point in the same direction so there is a nonzero total force.

@Donkey yes, it moves. Did anything I said lead you to believe that I think otherwise?

Then are you also of the opinion that the Feynman disc starts spinning due to emission of free traveling EM waves? This would not be the consensus explanation of this phenomenon.

@Donkey I am not of that opinion. As I said above “I am well aware of Feynman’s disk. This isn’t that”. Your concept is a photon rocket, not a Feynman’s disk. They are different things.

Ok then lets agree to disagree on this point.

@Donkey sounds good!
